# Bucle no itera todos los elementos, se corta en el indice 3. JS

Tags: javascript, array, bucles

acudo nuevamente al foro por un bug.
Previamente pude ordenar el string inicial en un *array*, separando los regalos. Luego los ordene y saque los que tienen "_" delante (que significa que estan tachados y no cuentan. Paso siguiente tuve que iterar el array para saber que elemento se repite y cuantas veces. Por ultimo tengo que meter el resultado en un objeto. El problema es que en la iteracion algo esta fallando, porque hay 2 coches y un peluche y la iteracion se frena en el indice 3 contando solo 1 coche, dejando afuera 1 y 1 peluche. No entiendo que esta sucediendo.

Agradezco su ayuda, saludos.

```js
// '_' NO SE CUENTA
//Transforma el texto a un objeto que contenga el nombre de cada regalo y las veces que aparece. 
console.log('------------------ ch2')

const carta = 'bici coche balón _playstation bici coche peluche'


//Separamos la lista sacando los espacios
let preListaRegalos = carta.split(' ')

console.log(preListaRegalos);

//paraCada elemento del array
// Si incluye "_"
//   eliminamelo del array
//devolver array actualizado
//Aca estamos filtrando la lista para que la arroje sin los tachados '_', ordenados
preListaRegalos = preListaRegalos.filter((i) => i[0] !== '_').sort();
console.log(preListaRegalos);

//Ahora contamos cuantas veces se repiten los regalos 
//BUG. A partir de coche deja de contar, solo suma 1 y no pasa a peluche. Puede que sea algo relacionado al length de la lista de conteo..

let contador = 1
let repetidorContainer = []

for(let i = 0; i < preListaRegalos.length; i++){
  if(preListaRegalos[i+1] === preListaRegalos[i]){
    contador++
  }else {
    repetidorContainer.push(contador);
    contador = 1;
  }
}

console.log(repetidorContainer);

//Aca hacemos un array con los elementos + las veces que se repiten. BUG, SOLO CUENTA HASTA EL INDEX 3, toma 1 solo coche y no toma peluche
let listaDefinitiva = []
for(let n = 0; n < repetidorContainer.length; n++){
  listaDefinitiva += (preListaRegalos[n] + ': ' + repetidorContainer[n] + ' ');
} 

console.log(listaDefinitiva);


//aca lo metemos en un objeto.
let listaObjeto = {}; //hasta aqui es objeto
for(let o = 0; o < repetidorContainer.length; o++){
  listaObjeto [preListaRegalos[o]] = repetidorContainer[o];
} 

console.log(listaObjeto);
```

Comment: [es.so] ***no es un foro***, es una comunidad de Preguntas y Respuestas. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Para sumar la cantidad de veces que se repite un valor de la lista y almacenarlo en un objeto puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```js
const lista = [
  "balón",
  "bici",
  "bici",
  "coche",
  "coche",
  "peluche"
];

const regalos = {};

lista.forEach(regalo => {
  regalos[regalo] = regalos[regalo] ? regalos[regalo] + 1 : 1;
});

console.log(regalos);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Como se observa en el código, genero un objeto vacío llamado `regalos`. Luego se recorre la lista de regalos y se agrega la cantidad a la clave correspondiente al regalo de la lista. Si el objeto no tiene una clave para el regalo, se crea una y se establece su valor a 1, si el objeto ya dispone de una clave para el regalo, se aumenta su cantidad en uno.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: Sos un capo. Me ahogué en un vaso de agua y meti como 3 ciclos cuando pude haberlo hecho en 1. Error de principiante, pero sirve para aprender. Muchas gracias!!!!